# How to deploy streamlit app that requires first compiling a package written in C

Tags: python, setup.py, streamlit

I am preparing an app that is making use of [IOU3D](https://github.com/Banconxuan/RTM3D/tree/master/src/lib/utils/iou3d) which is written in C and requires compilation.
On my local machine, this is not a problem to compile the package first before importing it in my app.
But my question is how to do that if I want to deploy the app to streamlit cloud.
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: you can compile it with `subprocess`

Comment: Thanks @RJAdriaansen . Can you elaborate on how to do this? I havent done it before, so no clue 

Comment: Well you can execute command line commands (git clone, make, etc. in your case) with `os.system` or `subprocess.run`, there is a lot of documentation on this online, see for example: https://dev.to/divshekhar/python-subprocess-execute-shell-commands-1bl2

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely have a look at this.